# Watir will not install with XP x86 or Win 7 x64. Getting error building native extension for the FFI gem 

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver

I am currently trying to install watir on my PC but currently hitting the errors below and I cannot think why this is happening?

I am following the steps below to install:

```
Download ruby 1.9.2: 
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/
 Install.

Download RubyGems:
 http://rubygems.org/pages/download
 Install.

Download the DevKit so that native extensions can be built:
     ruby dk.rb init
     ruby dk.rb review
     ruby dk.rb install

gem update --system (or to do more quickly: gem update --system --no-rdoc --no-ri)
     gem install watir
```

When I do this all I get is the error log below. Does anyone know how I can get Watir to install please?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\IE User\Desktop\Ruby and Eclipse>gem install watir
 Fetching: win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
 Fetching: windows-api-0.4.0.gem (100%)
 Fetching: windows-pr-1.2.1.gem (100%)
 Fetching: win32-process-0.6.5.gem (100%)
 Fetching: xml-simple-1.1.1.gem (100%)
 Fetching: hoe-2.12.4.gem (100%)
 Fetching: s4t-utils-1.0.4.gem (100%)
 WARNING: s4t-utils-1.0.4 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
 Fetching: builder-3.0.0.gem (100%)
 Fetching: user-choices-1.1.6.1.gem (100%)
 Fetching: commonwatir-2.0.4.gem (100%)
 Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.0-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
 Fetching: ffi-1.0.11.gem (100%)
 Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
 ERROR: Error installing watir:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

 checking for ffi.h... no
 checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include... no
 checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
 checking for ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()... yes
 checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
 checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
 creating extconf.h
 creating Makefile

make
 C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_ffi_c'" > ffi_c-i386-mingw32.def
 Configuring libffi
 make -C "/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"
 make[1]: Entering directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi'
 make "AR_FLAGS=" "CC_FOR_BUILD=" "CFLAGS=" "CXXFLAGS=" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=" "CFLA
 GS_FOR_TARGET=" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c
 -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -
 c" "JC1FLAGS=" "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "MAKE=make" "MAKE
 INFO=/bin/sh /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/mis
 sing --run makeinfo " "PICFLAG=" "PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=" "RUNTESTFLAGS=" "SHELL=/b
 in/sh" "exec_prefix=/usr/local" "infodir=/usr/local/share/info" "libdir=/usr/loc
 al/lib" "prefix=/usr/local" "AR=ar" "AS=as" "CC=gcc" "CXX=g++" "LD=c:/documents
 and settings/ie user/desktop/ruby and eclipse/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe" "NM=/usr
 /mingw/bin/nm" "RANLIB=ranlib" "DESTDIR=" all-recursive
 make[2]: Entering directory/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi'
 Making all in include
 make[3]: Entering directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi/include'
 make[3]: Nothing to be done forall'.
 make[3]: Leaving directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi/include'
 Making all in testsuite
 make[3]: Entering directory/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi/testsuite'
 make[3]: Nothing to be done for all'.
 make[3]: Leaving directory/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi/testsuite'
 Making all in man
 make[3]: Entering directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi/man'
 make[3]: Nothing to be done forall'.
 make[3]: Leaving directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi/man'
 make[3]: Entering directory/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/
 ffi_c/libffi'
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/debug.lo src/debug.c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/debug.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/debug.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/prep_cif.lo src/prep_ci
 f.c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/prep_cif.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/prep_cif.o

/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/types.lo src/types.c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/types.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/types.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/raw_api.lo src/raw_api.
 c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/raw_api.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/raw_api.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/java_raw_api.lo src/jav
 a_raw_api.c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/java_raw_api.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/java_r
 aw_api.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/closures.lo src/closure
 s.c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/closures.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/closures.o

/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./inc
 lude -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c -o src/x86/ffi.lo src/x86/ffi.
 c
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wa
 ll -g -fexceptions -c src/x86/ffi.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/x86/.libs/ffi.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iin
 clude -I./src -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -c -o src/x86/win32.lo src/x86
 /win32.S
 libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -I.
 -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -c src/x86/win32.S -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/x86
 /.libs/win32.o
 /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc -Wall -g -fexceptions -version-inf
 o grep -v '^#' ./libtool-version -no-undefined -o libffi.la -rpath /usr/local
 /lib src/debug.lo src/prep_cif.lo src/types.lo src/raw_api.lo src/java_raw_api.l
 o src/closures.lo src/x86/ffi.lo src/x86/win32.lo
 libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libffi.dll.a src/.libs/debug.o src/.libs/prep_cif.o
 src/.libs/types.o src/.libs/raw_api.o src/.libs/java_raw_api.o src/.libs/closur
 es.o src/x86/.libs/ffi.o src/x86/.libs/win32.o echo "X" | /usr/bin/sed -e 1
 s/^X// -e 's/ -lc$//' -link -dll
 c:/documents and settings/ie user/desktop/ruby and eclipse/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/
 mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -link
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[3]: *** [libffi.la] Error 1
 make[3]: Leaving directory /c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi'
 make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi'
 make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/f
 fi_c/libffi'
 make: *** ["/c/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/.li
 bs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.1
 1 for inspection.
 Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_m
 ake.out
```

I am totally at a loss as to how to rectify this. I have tried this on both XP x86 and Win 7 X64 to no avail.

Thanks in advance
 Andy

Comment: Try RubyInstaller (http://rubyinstaller.org/).

Comment: Added watir webdriver tag since I know this can be a problem there as well and might make it easier for someone else with this issue to get things going.

Comment: Looks like you did not install devkit correctly. Where did you install it? It would be the best if it was in path with no spaces, like `c:\devkit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the later versions of FFI have been a source of problems for some, both because they no longer include a native windows version and have to build one on the fly, but also due to some incompatabilities with watir or webdrivers

Try doing this

```
gem uninstall ffi 
 (just in case there is anything that managhed to get installed)
gem install ffi -v 1.0.9
```

Then install watir or watir-webdriver

**Update:**
 The latest versions of FFI work fine with Watir and Watir-Webdriver, however do not come 'precompiled' as earlier versions did.  So to install them on a PC If you do not already have it, you will need to get [Devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/).  Once you have devkit installed and have run the setup scripts for it, you can use `gem install ffi` to get the latest FFI gem installed and it should work just fine.

Comment: That is exceptional. Thank you so much, if I could give you 1000000000 repution points I would. This is incredible. I am going to add this my intall notes right now! Thanks Chuck!

Comment: Sadly the most you are allowed to do is upvote the answer and because it was your question, tick it as the answer (as you did).  But while the rep is nice, knowing it solved the problem is a better reward in my book.  That beats the heck out of people who never respond to answers and you don't know if their issue was addressed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my instructions on how to install Watir on Windows. If you follow them you will be able to install the latest versions of Ruby, Watir and ffi.

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md